# Easiest way to turn something a powerpoint into a video file

Tags: video, youtube

I am looking to turn my stories into YouTube videos. We have images set for the backgrounds. They currently aren't as PowerPoint files. They were going to be HTML pages however it would be easier for us to host these on YouTube as we have some issues loading sounds and the javascript scrolling at the same time.

**Already Tried** : using the YouTube video editor however I cannot fill the screen enough.

**Requirement** : Cheaply create video files using background images, simple transitions and adding sound.

**My Experience level** : Not expert, not done since a long time.

What is the easiest/most cost effective way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iMovie comes free on Mac computers, and it includes all of the features you're looking for. It's also very simple to use.  (I used it to make about 300 videos over the last 5 years.)

Comment: Sure! Let me know if you have any questions about it (like how to control its "Ken Burns" effect on still photos!).

Comment: It's worked really well thanks so much I've managed to get a basic outline of what I want and learn how to do it all in less than three hours! Completely overlooked IMovie...

Comment: Fantastic! People say it's not that great, but as I wrote in my answer I've edited 300 videos with it. I've even done special effects -- like making it look as though Thor (played by me) hammered a hole through my wall!

Comment: No it's perfect its so easy to use I'm not doing anything too strenuous with it and I wouldn't even know how to start bashing down a wall without actually bashing the wall!

Answer (score 3):

Not sure, which version you're using and I didn't use PowerPoint recently, but as far as I can remember, there is a [video export function built in](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Turn-your-presentation-into-a-video-c140551f-cb37-4818-b5d4-3e30815c3e83). Might be worth a try.

Also there's a list with [free video software on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_video_editing_software), which you can take a look at. Many of them should work for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a mac you can use quicktime to screen record the powerpoint in presentation mode and advance the slides as you wish. Then you can add music to it on Youtube